# Handle Excel.Range deletion using C#

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto

How to handle range deletion, like deletion of selected range, row or column? Excel only fires On_Worksheet_Changed with changed range without additional parameters, so I can't determine when user set value in cell and when cell gets value from shifted range.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect when rows have been deleted by user in Excel 2003](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800886/detect-when-rows-have-been-deleted-by-user-in-excel-2003)

Comment: It is for 2003 but as far as I know Office.Interop barely changed over the years.